# Method call with parameters

Tags: java, parameters

This is my first time with java, so be friendly

I have written a method in a class called book with the following header

```
public void removeDetails(String key)
```

If i wanted to call this method in a different class how would I do this?

```
    Book d = new Book();
    Book.removeDetails(String key);
```

I believe the only thing I am missing, is what to put in the parameters

Comment: You need an instance of the class the method is declared in. You can then call the method by invoking it on the instance. `theInstance.removeDetails("somevalue");`.

Comment: Take a look into the static keyword in java which allows you to access fields or methods through the class instead of an instance of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance of Book to call the method like this:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.removeDetails("string");
```

Or you can make removeDetails a static method like this:

```
public static void removeDetails(String argument) {}
```

Then you an call it the way you wanted (though there other considerations when you make a method static (like is cannot modify instance variables)

Comment: In your case you would do d.removeDetails.  Also this is a better answer then the one by Ross.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to declare the method as `static` in order to call it like that (without an instance being created).  To call it with an instance, you need to create an instance of the class it is defined in like so

```
 Book book = new Book();
 book.removeDetails();
```